# Obtain incremented counter value in promise in Google cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a new invoice number by using the incremented counter value. How can I obtain the incremented value (in a promise) after incrementing it?

Below is the code that I am using to increment.

```
db.doc(docRef).update({numberOfInvoices: FieldValue.increment(1)});
```

[Firestore counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to query the document after you have updated it, as follows:

```
db.doc(docRef).update({numberOfInvoices: FieldValue.increment(1)})
.then(() => {
   return db.doc(docRef).get();
})
.then(doc => {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
}).catch(error => {
    // ...
});
```

[`FieldValue.increment`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-increment) "returns a special value that can be used with `set()` or `update()` **that tells the server** to increment the field's current value by the given value". In other words, the calculation is done by the Firestore backend, and therefore you need to query the doc to get the new incremented value.

Comment: Doesn't this need to be done in a 'batch' or 'transactin' or something like that?  Or is there a guarantee that you'll read back the result of your increment and not another clients racing increment?

Comment: @P.T. "Doesn't this need to be done in a 'batch' or 'transactin' or something like that?" => No, as you will read in the [Firebase blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/increment-server-side-cloud-firestore.html), with `FieldValue.increment` the database would instantly make the change based on whatever value it has

Comment: The update is atomic on *the server*.  But I don't think the value the client reads in a subsequent `.get()` is consistent with its own increment.  I think something like https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#passing_information_out_of_transactions is needed.  Or, I haven't found the documentation that talks about getting the increment back to the client consistently.

Comment: (I guess I'm also assuming that the questioner wants to get back a consistent value, though they didn't explicitly state that -- it seems implied from the usage as an "invoice number".  It is what I want.)

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the incremented value by

```
let data =await db.doc(docRef).get(); //make sure the functions is async
let counts = data.val()['numberOfInvoices'];
```